# How to reset wizard style redux form?

Tags: redux-form

I am using the example http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/wizard/ to accomplish my own form.
But how can I reset the first and second form when I use the wizard style form?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your form by calling `dispatch(reset('myForm'));` after you have submitted the data ideally at the parent component.

You can read more about it here
https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/faq/howtoclear.md/

The tricky part is to make sure that `dispatch` is available at the component where you are submit (aka the parent component).

One way to do that is to wrap your parent component with connect(). After that, your component will receive a dispatch function as a prop. You can then use
`this.props.dispatch`.

This works for me

```
submitForm(values) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props


    axios.post(`YOUR_URL_HERE`, values)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        dispatch(reset('MY_FORM')); 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Unexpected error", error);
    });

}
```